# Where should I populate my Zend_Navigation container?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

Where in my application should I define my top level and lower-level pages for use by Zend Navigation? My top level navigation bar view helper is going to be separate from the view helper that generates the sub navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way is to define all your navigation in a single place. It supports unlimited nested (child) pages, meaning you can have your main menu as the base level and then the sub-pages under each main page for your sub-menus. Using the View Helpers you can easy output only the sub-page menu for the current active page automatically.

This way keeps all your navigation in a single place, for future maintainability.

For example, I define my site-wide navigation within the application.ini file using the [Application Resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.navigation), and then within my view scripts use the [Navigation View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.navigation) to format my menus.

This is a small extract from my application.ini file navigation config in a project I am working on:

```
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.label                   = "Exhibits"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.controller              = "exhibits"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.action                  = "index"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.index.label       = "Search Exhibitors"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.index.controller  = exhibits
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.index.action      = index
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.search.label      = "Search Exhibits"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.search.controller = exhibits
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.search.action     = "search"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.new.label         = "New Exhibitor"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.new.controller    = exhibits
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.new.action        = "new"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.import.label      = "Import Exhibits"
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.import.controller = exhibits
resources.navigation.pages.exhibits.pages.import.action     = "import"

resources.navigation.pages.sales.label                      = "Sales"
resources.navigation.pages.sales.controller                 = "sales"
resources.navigation.pages.sales.action                     = index
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.index.label          = "Review/Search"
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.index.controller     = sales
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.index.action         = index
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.edit.label           = Add/Edit Sales
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.edit.controller      = sales
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.edit.action          = edit
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.flags.label          = Flags/Problems
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.flags.controller     = sales
resources.navigation.pages.sales.pages.flags.action         = flags
```

And within my layout.phtml file:

```
<div id='mainmenu'>
  <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(0); ?>
</div> <!-- #mainmenu -->
<div id='submenu'>
  <?php echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setOnlyActiveBranch(true)
                                        ->setMinDepth(1)
                                        ->setMaxDepth(1); ?>
</div> <!-- #submenu -->
```

So when a user goes to the Exhibits page, they only see the children of that page, and the same with the Sales page. Pretty simple and very effective.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you! Instead of specifying controllers and actions, can I use route names instead? That way I can simply modify the route and the change will be reflected in the navigation.

Comment: I've never used them in Zend_Navigation, but yes you can. The *.route parameter can be used for each page to specify the router to use. See [Zend Navigation Pages MVC](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.pages.html#zend.navigation.pages.mvc) for usage.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this in the controller plugin. Here I can create navigation based on the current route or request parameters, and then easily pass to the view/layout from the application resource and switch with another one, when navigation is redesigned.

Comment: So I should use a dedicated controller plugin to do this?